# Can one define wedge products using determinants for $n$-forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, exterior-algebra

I was talking to Ted Shifrin in math chat yesterday and he mentioned there is a way to define wedge products using determinants.

As far as I understand, given a set of vectors $x,y,z,v,u... \in \Bbb{R}^n$, the wedge product is an operation defined on those vectors such that

1. $v \wedge v = 0$
2. $u \wedge v = - v \wedge u$
3. $cu\wedge v= c(u\wedge v)$
4. $(u_1 + u_2) \wedge v = u_1 \wedge v + u_2 \wedge v $

   $u\wedge (v_1 + v_2) = u \wedge v_1 + u \wedge v_2 $

Apart from this, I really don't know much about it. I tried understanding this concepts using tensor products and free vector spaces, but since I didn't get anywhere with that, I'm still unsure what a wedge product is other than abstractly via those axioms.

This answer provides an example how to define wedge products for a 2-form: 
[Wedge product and determinants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833379/wedge-product-and-determinants)

**My Question:**

1. Does the determinant definition of a wedge product work for $n$-forms?
2. If this definition using determinants is satisfactory, why do I see wedge products defined more often using free vector spaces and or tensor products?

Comment: $0)$ There's a difference (though some would say only a slight difference) between the wedge product of vectors and the wedge product of differential forms.  $1)$ Yes.  It's $\varphi_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \varphi_n (v_1, \dots, v_n) = \frac 1{n!} \operatorname{det} (\varphi_i (v_j))$.  $2)$ IDK.

Comment: (2) people do it to avoid picking a basis. That becomes important when doing algebraic or differential geometry.