# Determinant and wedge product confusion

Tags: determinant, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Beginner with differential forms – please go easy. I'm trying to understand how the wedge product can be used to define the determinant. In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (bottom of page 210) he gives$$\omega^{1}\wedge\cdots\,\wedge\omega^{k}\left(X_{1},\ldots,X_{k}\right)=\det\left(\omega^{i}\left(X_{j}\right)\right).$$However, in this question [Can one define wedge products using determinants for $n$-forms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170971/can-one-define-wedge-products-using-determinants-for-n-forms) one of the comments gives$$\varphi_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\varphi_{n}(v_{1},\dots,v_{n})=\frac{1}{n!}\det(\varphi_{i}(v_{j})).$$I might have the wrong end of the stick, but both things look the same except for that $\frac{1}{n!}$. What have I missed?

Comment: It's just a matter of convention, though the first expression seems to be more usual

Comment: But doesn't that $\frac{1}{n!}$ make the two expressions different?

Comment: it does. It's just a different convention of what the LHS means

Comment: Some authors choose to have the volume of the unit cube be $1/n!$ to simplify a few other formulas. Others of us would rather have the cube have volume $1$.

Comment: There is nothing about wedge products on page 210 of either of the published editions of _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_. You must be using one of the pirated draft versions of the first edition, which somebody posted illegally on the internet. Those are full of mistakes and come with no guarantees. If you look at the published second edition, you'll find this discrepancy explained on pages 356-358.

Comment: @JackLee - Thank you, that answers my question. Two definitions of the wedge product - sneaky!